# Decrypt using BCPGP private key in python

Tags: python, encryption, password-encryption, pgp, openpgp

How do I read BouncingCastle PGP key and decrypt message using Python.?

This private key is generated using `GoAnywhere OpenPGP Studio`, password is `Test@123`

Below is the key blob and the error I'm getting. I'm getting same error when I read from file`(.asc)` as well

```
test_key_pvt = """-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.48
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=Uo6i
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
"""
```

*`pvt_key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_blob(test_key_pvt)`*

**Error**: `pgpy.errors.PGPError: 6 is not a valid SymmetricKeyAlgorithm`

**Another error for different key**: `pgpy.errors.PGPError: 112 is not a valid CompressionAlgorithm`

Not able to arrive at any solution, I'm trying to automate a very small transfer and its really annoying that I'm not able to find anything for this in python. `PGPY` library doesn't have a lot of documentation.

TIA